# Magento 2: Not showing customers in backend grid

Tags: magento2, reindex, magento-2.0.2

There are customers imported from Magento 1.9.1.0 which are in customer eav customer_entity and related tables. But admin customer grid shows no records. I have also tested adding new customer from the backend, they are added. Those imported customers can login in the frontend. Customer Index Management always shows processing.

[image]

I have tried to manually reindex `bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid`.

It doesn't seem to do anything. I don't think setting up cron will help either. However, it is my localhost.

> Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like some error happened in the process of re-index and index status left processing. You need to reset it DB.

For example by query:

```
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';
```

Then run:

```
php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Awesome @KAndy. It worked. As you said, the status was 'working'. I changed it to invalid and rerun the indexer command : bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid. Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Magento 2 not showing customers in backend grid:

Run the below commands for fix

```
1) php bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid

2) php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Raph and Nithin, but the command you gave doesn't reindex if the status of the index is not "invalid". Meaning reindexing will ignore "valid" and "processing" statuses. These are defined in the indexer table. So the solution of @KAndy works. And the we can do php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid as you suggest.

Answer (score 6):

Best option is to reset and then reindex via CLI

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid
php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```