# Magento 2: Admin Customer Listing Not Displaying Record

Tags: magento2, admin, customer

I have an entry of 54K users in Customers. In Database `customer_entity` table it's showing count.

It's working an hour before. Suddenly it's not displaying in Admin Customer Listing. Trying to search as well. Still not displaying record.

I have cleared cache as well. No errors in Log

**What's the reason behind this issue or why it occurs?** Because Magento behaves strangely.

Comment: Is there any customer from `customer_grid_flat` table?

Comment: `customer_grid_flat` table is Blank :( No records. It's 0

Comment: Tried to reindex database?

Comment: Let me do that `static:content-deploy` is not going to affect right?

Comment: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Yes  done but no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47155/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-khoa-truongdinh).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reset your databse: [Magento 2: Not showing customers in backend grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115064/magento-2-not-showing-customers-in-backend-grid)

<del>`update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';`</del>

**[EDIT]:**

We should use

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid
```

### Possible errors:

### --Disable safe mode

> update magento.indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status !=
>   'valid'   Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried
>   to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable
>   safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and
>   reconnect.    0.000 sec

Reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench

#### --Not able to run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid`

> Customer Grid index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.

```
show processlist; 
kill "id number";
```

Or, we can restart mysql server.

#### --A large number of database - php -dmemory_limit=512M

If you have a large number of database, run the command with

```
php -dmemory_limit=512M bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

Or should increase the `memory_limit` ~ 512M in `php.ini`

Comment: Should be: php bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid instead of php bin/magento indexer:rest customer_grid

Comment: php -dmemory_limit=512M bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid its worked for me

Answer (score 8):

I will NOT recommend to mess with Magento database directly.

Try this:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid
php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

Comment: Thanks @alta-works, your solution is much easy and straight forward.