# Magento 2 customer data indexing error

Tags: magento2, customer-account, indexing, customer-grid

I have updated Magento 1.9.X to Magento 2.1.3. I have used `magento2_data_migration-0.1.25` When i was importing I got an error in `customer_group` table so I have manually imported it from previous database.

Now when I logged in at back-end in Magento 2 there is no customer data. I checked tables data is there. When I am trying to re-index I got an error.

Attached the screen shot for indexing.

[image]

Anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: Try `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` & 
`update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';`

Comment: It haven't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your database: [Magento 2 not showing customers in backend grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115064/magento-2-not-showing-customers-in-backend-grid?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';
```

**--A large number of database** - `php -dmemory_limit=2064M`

If you have a large number of database, run the command with

```
php -dmemory_limit=2064M bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

Comment: it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your magento root directory by using command line of your operationg system

example:- root directory of localhost server magento is /var/www/html/sample_folder/magento

so by the example of localhost type cd 'space' /var/www/html/sample_folder/magento

after it type this or copy/paste this command
"php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid"

it will show the record of latest imported customers in all customers in magento admin