# Magento 2 data migration 'Permission denied' error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, configuration, magento2-migration-tool, core-config-data

I am trying to migrate magento 1.9 data to magento 2.

A week ago I was able to do settings verfication and run migrate data command than I have to stop work. Now after coming back when I try to resume same work I got an error.

I am beginer in Magento please, tell me fix for this.This is the same error I am getting while trying to cross check settings and to migrate data.

[image]

Comment: Are you not using ubertheme data migration tool ?

Comment: Try this service 
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-upgrade-migration.html

Comment: Its a problem of permission set 777 to all of your project folder or make sure that the owner of project is the same of the user used for execute the command

Answer (score 1):

set config.xml at the end, ie:

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce/1.9.3.4/config.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you should try ubertheme data migration tool.

https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-tool/

https://magecomp.com/blog/migrating-magento-1-x-to-magento-2-0/

Comment: I have tried that but it gives me error in customer data it haven't synced the customer data. Every time I got an error while syncing customer data.

Comment: What error can you please show error message ?

Comment: Below is the error I am getting
[link] http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154960/magento-2-customer-data-indexing-error

Comment: any update on that?