# Reindexing does not go through - Magento2 on Localhost - Using MAMP

Tags: magento2, database, cron, reindex, magento2.2.2

Unfortunately, I stopped by some issue I cannot find the answer for, no matter how much I search online.

When I attempt to reindex through terminal using the following code:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Only the first table (Design Config Grid) seems to be properly rebuilt:

[image: Only design grid is rebuilt]

In the Admin panel, the only table that is not reindexed is the "Customer Grid" table:

[image: The customer Grid is not reindexed]
I am assuming the reason must be related to the "Customer Grid". Would you please help me figure this out? Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Magento 2.2.2

Comment: I have also been struggling with this exact issue all day. I will post a solution if I manage to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are some excellent suggestions at [Magento 2: Not showing customers in backend grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115064/magento-2-not-showing-customers-in-backend-grid)

Namely:

`php bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid`

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid`

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to figure this out my end. I have a few things for you to try out. Firstly I would recommend enabling error_reporting in your php.ini file. This will output where the fatal error occurred.

When I enabled error reporting this is the error it returned:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Locale' not found in [root]/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php:64
```

If you get this same error it is likely you don't have the intl php extension installed on your server. I did have this installed on php7.1, but because I was on shared hosting and servers default php version was 7.0, this meant the shell was using php7.0.

So what I did was point my shell to the directory of the php version I wanted to use and then ran the indexer.

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**NOTE**

I found the path to my php version by running this command in the shell.

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

This then gave me a general idea of the path to where my PHP version was located:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc
Loaded Configuration File => /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.ini
```

From this `/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc` part of the response I worked out the path to my php7.1 install was:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php
```

Hopefully this resolves your issue, or at least points you in the right direction.